# Angular 6 Aux Routing

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-routing, angular6

So the idea is that I'm navigating to an admin page, & then want to load various components within that page using a side nav only on that page.

So I'm pretty sure an aux route is the best case for this, tell me if I'm wrong.

```
  { path: 'userAccounts', component: UserManagementComponent, canActivate: [LoggedInGuard]},
  { path: 'admin', component: AccountCreationPageComponent, outlet:'admin' },

<div class="navigation_items" *ngFor="let x of data" 
 [routerLink]="[ { outlets: { 'admin':['admin']}}]">{{x.id}}</div>
    <router-outlet name="admin"></router-outlet>
```

Basically I'm assuming my syntax is wrong somewhere, or I haven't quite understood how Aux routes work, as this wont display the admin path

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: well explained Angular routing [here](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-2-router-nested-routes-and-nested-auxiliary-routes-build-a-menu-navigation-system/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear that the child route had to be nested within the parent route so

```
  {
    path: 'userAccounts', component: UserManagementComponent, canActivate: [LoggedInGuard], children: [
      { path: 'admin', component: AccountCreationPageComponent, outlet: 'admin' }
    ]
  }
```

Did the trick.

Comment: You could also go for a so called 'named-route'